# Control code from .bat file C#

Tags: c#, batch-file

I am new to C# community. 
I have a console application that I initiate it by batch file. The `.bat` file contains the following:

```
AffiliationParser.exe "D:\programs\AffiliationParser\Debug\New folder" 
pause
```

When I run the batch file I wanna the code extract the `Folder Path` and get every `.txt` file into the path and apply rest of the code.

When I run the code from debugging, it works greatly. **The problem is**, when run with the batch file, it shows an error of:

> Unhandled Exception: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'D:\programs\Debug\New folder\'.

Note the path provided in the error above is **not** the same path I wrote it in the `.bat` file. I wrote it previously, actually I don't know where is the problem.

My source code is:

```
using(StreamReader batch=new StreamReader(@"D:\programs\AffiliationParser\Debug\Run.bat")) {
    string bat;

    while(!batch.EndOfStream) {
        bat=batch.ReadLine();

        // do your processing with batch command

        if(bat=="pause") {
            continue;
        }

        string fpath=bat.Substring(bat.IndexOf(" \""));
        string path=fpath.Replace("\"", "");
        string[] name=Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.txt");
        string words=name.Min();
        string word=words.Substring(words.LastIndexOf("\\")).Replace("\\", "");
        string Oword=word.Replace(".txt", "");

        Console.ForegroundColor=ConsoleColor.Yellow;
        Console.WriteLine("================================In progress=====================================");
        Console.WriteLine("Working on File "+word+" in the Path "+path);
    }
}
```

So please help me and sorry if I can't explain my problem correctly.

Comment: Can you provide the exact line of the error and the exact text of the message?  Also, if you're using the commandline, it would be useful to see the code that actually retrieves the command line.  It should be fairly obvious what's happening once you pinpoint that.

Comment: at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1.CommonInit()
   at System.IO.FileSystemEnumerableIterator`1..ctor(String path, String origina
lUserPath, String searchPattern, SearchOption searchOption, SearchResultHandler`
1 resultHandler)
   at System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(String path, String searchPattern)
   at AffiliationParser.Program.Main(String[] args) in D:\Developing\REF\Affilia
tionParser\AffiliationParser\AffiliationParser\Program.cs:line 44`

Comment: this the rest of the error Dan

Comment: In your program you are apparently parsing a hardcoded batchfile, instead of grabbing the path ([see here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/acy3edy3.aspx))you supplied in the batchfile that you used to start your program. Are you sure those two batchfiles are the same?

Comment: Which directory the batch file ran from? Is it "D:\programs\AffiliationParser\Debug\New folder" or is it "D:\programs\Debug\New folder\", espcially in command line, if you do not change the directory using the CD command, the default directory will be the directory it was started.

Comment: Ok guys i am sure that the path is correct and no path like "D:\programs\Debug\New folder" in my computer

Comment: @MohamedSayed: I mean, which line of code does the error occur on?  Which is line 44 of your source code?

Comment: yup @DanPuzey `string word = words.Substring(words.LastIndexOf("\\")).Replace("\\", "");` this is the line 44

Comment: So there is a text file in your batch file with the wrong path. Can you stick a break point at that line and check the value of the "word"?

Comment: @MohamedSayed: I can't see how that line of code can *possibly* be throwing the exception you describe given the code you've pasted.  Are you sure you're running/debugging what you think you're running/debugging?

Comment: i discovered the problem guys it it was my fault i forget to rebuild the solution so it was read another batch file sorry for the error and i apologize for your time thank you all for helping me

Comment: Thank you DanPuzey, Jegan and HansKesting